# React Native:How to dynamically arrange local images in display when picked from local gallery?

Tags: react-native, react-native-image-picker

In my RN 0.62.2 app, a function is used to display local images picked from gallery:

```
const displayImg = (img_source, width, ht, local=false) => {
        if (local) {
            return (<Image source={require(img_source)} style={{width:width, height:ht, resizeMode:'cover'}}/>); //<<<== require causes error with dynamic image source
        } else {  //online 
            return (<FastImage source={{uri:img_source}} resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover} style={{width:width, height:ht}}/>);
        };
        
    };
```

But because of the image source is not available when bundling, the RN throws [error](http://const%20displayImg%20=%20(img_source,%20width,%20ht,%20local=false)%20=%3E%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(local)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%3CImage%20source=%7Brequire(img_source)%7D%20style=%7B%7Bwidth:width,%20height:ht,%20resizeMode:%27cover%27%7D%7D/%3E);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%20%20//online%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20(%3CFastImage%20source=%7B%7Buri:img_source%7D%7D%20resizeMode=%7BFastImage.resizeMode.cover%7D%20style=%7B%7Bwidth:width,%20height:ht%7D%7D/%3E);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D;) for the `require`. The purpose of the function above is to dynamically arrange the image display format by the number of images picked. For example, for 1 image, then the image displayed will take full width. If there are 2 images, then one image will take half width side by side with another image. Since the app does not know which image to display until users pick the miage, the `require(image_source)` won't know the exact path when bundling and this is violation in React Native bundling. Is there way I can get around of this?

Comment: Don't use require for user input images. Just use {uri: img_source} because react-native-image-picker will return uri of picked image

Comment: `bravemaster`, thank you for the info. I thought `require` has to be used for local image. Yes, image picker does return a path for the  local image picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to require user input images.

You should use them as external images because react-native-image-picker will return url of picked image.

So instead of

```js
 <Image source={require(img_source)} />
```

you should:

```js
<Image source={{uri: img_source}} />
```

Comment: `'bravemaster`, for a `'path : ', 'file:///data/user/0/com.xyz_app/cache/react-native-image-crop-picker/20160906_112918_HDR.jpg'`, it shows an empty box without image and error. Removed the resizeMode and only leave with style and it is the same. What else shall I correct?